# Graphite vs Elastic Metrics Beat for Windows Performance Counters

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana, graphite, metricbeat

I work with a web api, that makes heavy use of Windows Performance Counters. Until now this has not been collected in a good tool.

I would like to start making this data available in a place where we can create dashboards etc.

We already have an Elastic Search Cluster. I am only an enduser when it comes to Elastic. I do not have administrator knowledge. But I have heard about Metric Beats that as far as I can understand is intended for exactly Windows Performance Counters.

But I have also worked with Graphite and Grafana for these types of data in the past.

I have also heard that you can use Grafana as a dashboard tool on top of Metric Beats, is that correct?

I don't know what the best choice is, and I haven't been able to find comparisons on this on the web. So I am hoping someone here can enlighten me.

I also have a sneaky suspicion that I might have misunderstood something since I cannot find comparisons out there.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a quite subjective question you'll get different answers depending on who you ask.

Anyway, there are three parts:

1) collections of metrics

2) storage of metrics

3) display of metrics

Metrics beats is a collector. I do not know which collectors are suitable for Windows, popular collectors are is Collectd, Telegraf, Beats, Diamond. You basically need to find one which collects the data you are interested in. If you are interested in application metrics you can also plug in a library in your application. A popular choice for Java is Dropwizzard.

Then you'll need some database to store those metrics in. For data storage you can use Graphite, InfluxDB, Elastic, etc, whatever suits your requirements.

And then for displaying the metrics you can basically choose between Grafana, Kibana, and think influxdata has something as well.

If you don't have any specific requirements most of the mentioned tools will do fine.